# Drag and drop and updating menu-submenu combine with menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom functionality for changing order of published pages and posts and private pages and posts programmatically. But how can I make that listing as menu/sub-menu items in main menu programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Short codes in menu.
First, use this snippet in functions.php to add shortcode support in wordpress menu :

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');
```

then, you can create shortcode to show your last posts and use in into your menu.
for example :

```
<?php

// function that runs when shortcode
function show_last_post_shortcode() { 

// WP Query Parameters
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' );
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 
?> 
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php 
// Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

} 

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('show_last_post', 'show_last_post_shortcode'); 

?>
```

Comment: I need to display Page listing as menu-item/submenu-item and also use drag and drop and update the main-menu as well as the order of the pages at the same time.